# Why the result was different in python Sympy.limit?

Tags: python, limit, sympy

I guess both of them are equal(in python/sympy):

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol('x')

limit(sin(x)/x,x,0)

#(result 1)

limit(sin(1/x)*x,x,00)

#(result 0 !!!)
```

In actually, `let y = 1/x, limit(sin(1/x)*x,x,00) = limit(sin(y)/y,y,0)`, right?

(in anaconda 64-bit,ipython notebook, python 2.7, sympy0.7.6)

Comment: No, and this is a mathematical answer rather then pythonic. By your definition x approaches 0, y will approach 1. I think this is the the difference

Comment: http://www.math.washington.edu/~conroy/general/sin1overx/ (or did you mean infinity? that would be `oo` instead of `00`)

Comment: you are right. that should be oo instead of 00. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use oo (oo is infinity) instead of 00.

Answer (score 3):

To more exactly, use `sympy.oo`

```
import sympy as sym
from IPython.display import display,Math
fx = (1+1/x)**x
lim_pnt = sym.oo
lim = sym.limit(fx,x,lim_pnt)

display(Math('\\lim_{x\\to %s} %s = %s' %(lim_pnt,sym.latex(fx),sym.latex(lim))))
```